# Sensitivity analysis of SOCP (parametric programming)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Recently I am studying a problem which boils down as follows:

$$\epsilon_1 = \underset{\epsilon}{\mathop{\arg \min}}\; \epsilon^{\top}\epsilon$$
$$s.t.\quad \mathbb{a}^{\top}\epsilon + R\|\mathbb{b} + \epsilon\|_{2} = c,$$

where $\mathbb{a}$, $\mathbb{b}$, $c$ and $R$ are given and $R$ is positive. Suppose that the problem above is feasible. I was wondering how the optimal solution changes if $R$ is perturbed by a small quantity $\delta$, which results in the following problem:

$$\epsilon_2 = \underset{\epsilon}{\mathop{\arg \min}}\; \epsilon^{\top}\epsilon$$
$$s.t.\quad \mathbb{a}^{\top}\epsilon + (R+\delta)\|\mathbb{b} + \epsilon\|_{2} = c.$$

My intuition is that $\|\epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2\|$ is $O(\|\delta\|)$ (when $\delta$ is small enough), but I don't have the exact analytical solution. I found in this [reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-012-0586-z), property 1 shows that if $c$ rather than $R$ is perturbed by $\delta$, then the claim that $\|\epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2\|$ is $O(\|\delta\|)$ seems correct.

Comment: This work has the ingredients for solving this question. https://www.jstor.org/stable/3690633

Comment: You can answer your own question

Comment: Including that reference just in case someone gets similar questions.

Comment: Comments are not reached by the search engine, are they?